# Display attachments of a blog on Post.aspx

Tags: 2013, blog

I want to show the associated attachment/s with a particular blog on "Post.aspx" page in SharePoint 2013. Is there any way to meet this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function BlogAttachmentMethod() {    
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl);

    var web = clientContext.get_web();
    attachmentFolder = web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Lists/Posts/Attachments/' + postID);
    clientContext.load(attachmentFolder);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function () {
        attachmentFiles = attachmentFolder.get_files();
        clientContext.load(attachmentFiles);

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
    }), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

    setTimeout(function () {
        //id of div to which attachments need to bind
        var parent = document.getElementById("commandBar0").parentElement;
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.id = "divAttachments";
        div.innerHTML = orderList;

        parent.appendChild(div);
    }, 4000);
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {    
    orderList = "<span><b>Attachments</b></span>";
    orderList += "<ul>";
    var count = attachmentFiles.get_count();
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var serverRelativeURL = attachmentFiles.itemAt(i).get_serverRelativeUrl();
        var fileName = serverRelativeURL.substring(serverRelativeURL.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, serverRelativeURL.length);
        //alert(fileName);
        orderList += "<li><a href='" + serverRelativeURL + "'>" + fileName + "</a></li>";
    }
    orderList += "</ul>";    
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    orderList = "";
    //alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a REST call it get attachments from the list item. You can also utilize JSLink's postRender method to do the query.

```
var itemId = location.search.split('ID=')[1];

$(document).ready(function(){
    var p = $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Posts')/items(" + itemId + ")?$select=ID,Attachments,AttachmentFiles&$expand=AttachmentFiles",
        type: "GET",
        headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
    });

    p.done(function (data) {
        var item = data.d;
        var str = "";
        if (item.Attachments && item.Attachments == true) {
            str += "<div class='attachments'>";
            var attachmentsArr = item.AttachmentFiles.results;
            for (var i = 0; i < attachmentsArr.length; i++) {
                str += "<i class='fa fa-paperclip'></i> <a href='" + attachmentsArr[i].ServerRelativeUrl + "'>" + attachmentsArr[i].FileName + "</a>";
                if (i != attachmentsArr.length - 1) {
                    str += "<br/>";
                }
            }
            str += "</div>";
        }

        $("div.ms-blog-postBody").prepend(str);
    });
});
```

Comment: I used ClientContext instead Rest API call to fetch attachments and it worked successfully. I will also try your code.